# Developing Next.js with SWC minify in Docker with bind mount and Yarn 3: missing swc-linux-x64-gnu linux binary

Tags: docker, docker-compose, next.js, yarnpkg, swc-compiler

I am developing with Next.js on my Mac OS host using Docker running Ubuntu 18 and bind mounting my development directory to the container. I want to know if there is any way when using SWC Minify in Next.js 12+ to not have to copy over the whole host build context to Docker and then use a `yarn install` build step and a persistent volume to run a development environment in Docker because of the missing `@next/swc-linux-x64-gnu` binary.

Relevant part of `docker-compose.yaml`

```yaml
  # Next.js Client and Server
  my-nextjs:
    container_name: my-nextjs
    build:
      context: ./www
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      # bind mounting my development directory to /app in Docker
      - ./www:/app/
    ports:
      - "3911:3000"
```

I know that because it will be running on Linux and not Mac, Next.js SWC Minify will need a different binary so I explicitly add that to my dependencies on my Host machine with Yarn 3 (set to `nodeLinker: node-modules` in .yarnrc)

But that does ***not*** install the package to my host `node_modules` folder even though it is zipped in the `.yarn/cache` folder and appears in my package.json dependencies. I'm not sure why, and I think it's the reason for this problem.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# Install Node.js
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install curl
RUN apt-get -y install sudo
RUN useradd -m docker && echo "docker:docker" | chpasswd && adduser docker sudo
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential

# Install Yarn
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
RUN sudo apt-get update
RUN sudo apt-get install yarn

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 3000
ENV PORT 3000

ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

CMD ["yarn", "dev"]
```

When I try run this container I get:

```
 ❯  docker compose up my-nextjs                                                      
[+] Running 1/1
 ⠿ Container my-nextjs  Recreated                                                                                                                                                        0.1s
Attaching to my-nextjs
my-nextjs  | ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
my-nextjs  | info  - Loaded env from /app/.env
my-nextjs  | warn  - SWC minify release candidate enabled. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/swc-minify-enabled
my-nextjs  | info  - Attempted to load @next/swc-linux-x64-gnu, but it was not installed
my-nextjs  | info  - Attempted to load @next/swc-linux-x64-gnux32, but it was not installed
my-nextjs  | info  - Attempted to load @next/swc-linux-x64-musl, but it was not installed
my-nextjs  | error - Failed to load SWC binary for linux/x64, see more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/failed-loading-swc
my-nextjs exited with code 1
```

I have figured out a workaround for this... adding `- /app/node_modules` to the docker-compose volumes to allow the container to persist that folder and in the Dockerfile:

```
COPY . /app/
RUN yarn install
```

Which gets the correct binary and persists it in its **own** `node_modules` **over** the bind mounted `node_modules` folder. But I'm just trying to see if there's a way to do it without copying over the whole thing from the build context. I'm sure that if Yarn 3 would actually install `@next/swc-linux-x64-gnu` to `node_modules` on my host then this could be possible.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

In `<repoDir>/.yarnrc`, add:

```
--ignore-platform true
```

(Valid for yarn 1. You might want to double-check for later versions.)

Then run:

```sh
yarn add --dev @next/swc-linux-x64-gnu
```

This will install the Linux version of SWC in your `node_modules`, regardless of the platform, and you'll be able to use that in docker containers.

Trade-offs:

- you lose the platform check for packages you install in the future
- it won't be updated automatically when you update Next, you'll have to do it manually